Firebase Messaging service worker cannot be registered when running on Github pages
I have a Flutter Web app that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), when I run the app locally everything functions fine, but when I deploy the app to Github Pages the services worker cannot be registered
Failed to get FCM token: [firebase_messaging/failed-service-worker-registration] Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://here-for-help.github.io/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('https://here-for-help.github.io/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. .

I guess the problem is that instead of  https://here-for-help.github.io/firebase-messaging-sw.js it should look for the file under the subdomain https://here-for-help.github.io/project/firebase-messaging-sw.js but I cannot get this to work.
This is my web/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">
  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="project">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
  <title>project</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="flutter_bootstrap.js" async>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js', {
          scope: '/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope',
        });
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>

I deploy the app via this makefile (make deploy OUTPUT=project)

BASE_HREF = /project/
# Replace this with your GitHub username
GITHUB_USER = here_for_help
GITHUB_REPO = https://github.com/$(GITHUB_USER)/$(OUTPUT)
BUILD_VERSION := $(shell grep 'version:' pubspec.yaml | awk '{print $$2}')

# Deploy the Flutter web project to GitHub
deploy:
    @echo "Clean existing repository"
    flutter clean

    @echo "Getting packages..."
    flutter pub get

    @echo "Generating the web folder..."
    flutter create . --platform web

    @echo "Building for web..."
    flutter build web --base-href $(BASE_HREF) --release

    @echo "Deploying to git repository"
    cd build/web && \
    git init && \
    git add . && \
    git commit -m "Deploy Version $(BUILD_VERSION)" && \
    git branch -M main && \
    git remote add origin $(GITHUB_REPO) && \
    git push -u -f origin main

    @echo "✅ Finished deploy: $(GITHUB_REPO)"
    @echo " Flutter web URL: https://$(GITHUB_USER).github.io/$(OUTPUT)/"

.PHONY: deploy

And for completeness, here my firebase-messaging-sw.js file
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.0/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js");


try {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: XXXXXXXX,
    appId: XXXXXXXX,
    messagingSenderId: XXXXXXXX,
    projectId: XXXXXXXX,
    authDomain: XXXXXXXX,
    storageBucket: XXXXXXXX,
    measurementId: XXXXXXXX,
  });
  
  console.log('Firebase initialized successfully');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error initializing Firebase:', error);
}

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
  console.log('Received background message', payload);

  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification.body,
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});


Thank you!
I tried to set the filepath to /project/firebase-messaging-sw.js, this did not work for me.

I currently bypassed this issue by deploying to Cloudflare pages. There everything works correctly (because the files can be served from the root domain)
